# Takeover fails when restarting the highest priority node while the node with lowest is running

Tags: erlang, distributed

I have my application running on three nodes `pc`, `pc0`, `pc1`. At first when I started them together all started and the first node started running, When I quit the shell of first node, the second (pc0) started and when I quit the shell of second one, third (pc1) started running. But if I restart pc and pc0 while pc1 is still running, both of the nodes crashed saying that mandatory node pc1 is down. I am wondering, pc1 is running but the other nodes are saying `"pc1 is down"`.

`{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,kernel_config,{mandatory_nodes_down,['myapp@pc-1']}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}`

What may be the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

do you have global name regiser in your application? The procedure of takeover is to start application at high priority node first. Then shutdown the application at other node. That means you will have a short period that global name conflict.

Default global name conflict resolver is global:random_exit_name(). It will pick up pid randomly. So it may kill the process at high priority node and cause application shutdown.

My solution is always keep process register locally. So it is no problem at takeover. Then use global:re_register_name() to register global name.